# Google Maps V3 InvalidValueError Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

all I am building an app in Rails 5 Ruby 2.4.0 and I am trying to implement a dynamic google map that places a marker on a map for every location in the PostgresDB.

I am using the geocoder gem, and this is assigning my lat and lng float values.

> **when I use the following code:**

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = [
     <% @locations.each do |location| %>
       { lat:<%= location.latitude %>, lng:<%= location.longitude %> },
     <% end %>
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I get the following error in my console output in google chrome:

```
InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

screenshot of the error:
[image]

I'm relatively new to adding a dynamic map to a rails app, and not sure what to do to resolve this issue! any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

> **EDIT 1: Adds Script generated output:**

```
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = [
       { lat:51.0389453, lng:-113.9474975 },
       { lat:51.1015305, lng:-114.0411054 },
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

> **Edit 2: Adds Screenshot of errors:**
>   [image]

Comment: Please copy-paste the generated code of that part.

Comment: as in what its showing for the lat and lng?

Comment: Yeap. Seems like the problem lies there.

Comment: ok il go grab it

Comment: post updated i think this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using code for [single](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) marker. If you want to show more than one marker, you will have to add them as a [marker cluster](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) or loop through your array.

```
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = [
     <% @locations.each do |location| %>
       { lat:<%= location.latitude %>, lng:<%= location.longitude %> },
     <% end %>
    ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
    });
    for (i = 0; i < uluru.length; i++) {  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(uluru[i]['lat'], uluru[i]['lng']),
            map: map
        });
  }
```

Comment: Ok so using this, i am getting a few errors ill post them above:

Comment: updated the question EDIT # 2is where you can find the screenshot

Comment: @ShawnWilson looks like you need one more `}` to close out the for loop

Comment: so adding the extea close fixed the script so it runs error free however the map wont display anything. new question added for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689680/rails-5-dynamic-google-map-not-loading-no-console-errors-present

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the error is caused by you making an array of markers

```
var uluru = [
 <% @locations.each do |location| %>
   { lat:<%= location.latitude %>, lng:<%= location.longitude %> },
 <% end %>
];
```

then passing it in as a single marker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: uluru, #uluru is an array, not a LatLng
  map: map
});
```

It could also be that when you inject the location values with ERB they are injected as strings instead of floats here `{ lat:<%= location.latitude %>, lng:<%= location.longitude %> }` so you may want to make sure thats not happening as well.

## Edit: example of how I did it

index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV["key_name"] %>'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initIndexMap);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <%= content_tag "div", class: "index-map", id: "index-map", data: {json_markers: @json_parking_areas} do %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function initIndexMap() {
  //get markers from id:#index-map content_tag
  var jsonMarkers = $("#index-map").data("jsonMarkers");
  //set center
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(42.339169, -71.088474);
  //set bounds
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  
  //initialize map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('index-map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 4
  });

  //for loop to add markers          
  for (var i = 0; i <  jsonMarkers.length; ++i) {
    (function() {
      var latLng = {lat: jsonMarkers[i].lat, lng: jsonMarkers[i].lng};
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: jsonMarkers[i].infowindow
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: jsonMarkers[i].picture,
        label: jsonMarkers[i].title
      });    
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    })();
  }
}
```

Comment: so I am guessing you have some controller majic happening here too correct?

Comment: Kinda. The `@json_parking_areas` variable is an array of markers loaded from the database but once it gets to index.html.erb it will wait until the pages load, call `initIndexMap` which then looks for the item on the page with the id `index-map` and gets the data from that